# How to ban users in an anonymous chat?

Tags: security, chat

I have a chat application, where a user can just assign themselves a nickname and enter the chat to post their queries etc. This chat is public and one of its main points was to be anonymous.

But a few rogue users have started abusing the chat, so we tried banning them. We have a few ways like banning by nicks or by IPs but none of these are really robust.

What could be a proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to stay anonymous and fix your issue. The best solution is to limit the number of requests from the same IP address over some time. You can also check IP addresses or web sessions in a browser.

Comment: I don't think that this depends on the anonymous vs. identified state. If you don't have super-hard measures like trusted ID documents to be presented (driving license, passport, etc.), users can simply create more and more accounts. You would have to build up a reputational system similar to Stack Exchange where you have to "gain trust" of the community to be allowed for several actions. If you then just create another account, you will have lost all your reputation and probably your ability to disturb the system.